# converting monthly time series to quartely

Tags: r, time-series

I have converted my monthly time series to quarterly time series.
Month 1 is April and Month 12 is March.

```
     Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2013 48950305 82147447 64976400 66753437 67355925 70344107 69307385 70040361 69994761
```

I used this code to get quarterly series

```
test_agg <-  aggregate(pay,start = c(2013,4), nfrequency=4)
```

and got the result as below. Qtr2 below is supposed to be Qtr1 .
The first quarter of the year is (April-June) according to my data

my question is how do i make month (April- June) Qtr1

```
    Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4
2013           196076169 204455487 209344525
```

Output has to be like this

```
       Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4

2013   196076169 204455487 209344525  ...
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data with dput to reproduce your problem

Comment: added some indentations